# MySQL. insert into stored procedure affected rows' count is always 0

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I call a stored procedure from my c# code to insert a row into a table. My problem is that i always get 0 affected rows. Here are the codes

Stored procedure code

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddInfo`(
                    IN _activationDate datetime, 
                    IN _organization varchar(100),
                    IN _email varchar(45),  
                    IN _tableName varchar(35))
BEGIN
set @sqlquery = concat('insert into ', _tableName, ' values (?, ?, ?)');
prepare stmt from @sqlquery;
set @activationDate = _activationDate;
set @orgaization = _organization;
set @email = _email;

execute stmt using @activationDate, @orgaization, @email,;
deallocate prepare stmt;
END
```

C# code

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            string spName = "AddInfo";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(spName, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_activationDate", activationDate);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_organization", organization);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_email", email);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_tableName", tableName);

            conn.Open();

            int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            bool added = rowsAffected == 1 ? true : false;
            conn.Close();

            return added;
        }
```

when i run this code the row is successfully added to the table, but `rowsAffected` is always 0. Where is my problem? Thank you

Comment: Imagine a stored procedure that fills a temp table with some thousand rows, is using this rows to produce some output values and truncate the temp table at last. What would you expect as "affected rows"?

Comment: i know that ExecuteNonQuery should return the number of rows affected(see msdn). In my case it should return 1 as i add 1 row.But i get 0